# Change the motor or the gears?

Tags: motor, gear

I wonder, what's better to achieve some given torque? To chose a motor with the Kt that gives that torque or to choose a reduction drive that will output that torque from a given motor? I wonder what's the a benefits and side effects of choosing one over the other....for example, gears can be havier, but I think motors with greater Kt will need more magnets which can make them more expensive...is it there a nice way to balance the two of them?

Comment: Sometimes it makes me wonder how some questions are considered off topic and some don't. I've seen questions more related to electronic design being voted as off topic but a question about gears and motor torque apparently is considered on topic...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: Motors usually are between mechanical and eletronic design...choosing a motor means doing some electrical calculations. The answer to my question will be related to both mechanical electrical desing, since it's a balance between the 2 worlds...this question can be considered off topic by the electronics stack exchange, and in the mechanical stack exchange (if there was one) and it will have never been asked....or it can be considered on topic on both plataforms....the answer I am looking at will be relating Kt and Kv and widings dimensions and wheight which I think is very electrical..

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the torque and speed you need.

As a starting point, multiply the torque and the speed using Andy's formula to determine the motor power. Look at data on motors of similar power. If one offers the torque you need at a current within its safe ratings (i.e. operating current, NOT stall current), you can use it.

If not, you will need to gear down a faster running motor.

As a guideline, electric motors are most efficient when running near their unloaded speed (usually 75-90% of rated speed) at which their torque is 25% down to 10% of the stall torque. (This is useful when interpreting incomplete data sheets; sometimes they only list stall torque!) So it is a good idea to plan on running a motor fast, and gearing down to reduce the torque load.

Think about this some more : given a specific motor, with a specific magnet, the maximum torque (stall torque) is ultimately determined by the strength of that magnet. And a realistic torque is a fraction of that (say 10-20%). You can run a motor at its stall torque. But (for most motors) not for very long, even if the power supply will let you!

But nothing fundamental determines the maximum speed. Up to practical limits such as wear on brushes, bearings, heat from friction and resistance, you can run the motor as fast as you like and get more power out of it. But no more torque.

Can you increase Kt in the same motor? Absolutely. You can get more torque for the same current, by rewinding the motor with more turns (or buying it pre-wound to your requirements). However you have decreased Kv, since Kt*Kv = constant. (in SI units, Kt*Kv = 1). So the motor runs slower at the same voltage; overall you haven't gained anything. And the maximum torque is still the same : you just reach it at a lower current.

So Kt and Kv are about matching the motor's practical safe speed to your supply voltage, and then determining the stall current you need to supply to start it under a heavy load.

If that motor won't match your torque needs, then you choose between a bigger motor (heavier AND more expensive) or gearing. Gearing will often win...

Comment: Gears are also not 100% efficient, and they also get heavy, and expensive and demand lubrification...i wonder if there is a formula to help decide whether to find another motor or to place a gear on it's shaft....It's too much "feeling" I guess...

Comment: True but gear losses are *usually* small compared to motor losses. Properly formed and depthed gear teeth *roll* over each other rather than sliding, so lubrication is less important than for journal bearings. For example you **never** lubricate clock or watch gearing, but high power levels have other considerations...

Comment: true but also depends on the configuration...worm gears only slide due to friction and are not much efficient, and high spinning motors will need some lubricant in the gears eventually...

Answer (score 0):

Mechanical power into a load is 2\$\pi n T\$ where n is revs per second and T is torque. That's the nice relationship and if you need low speed and high torque more than likely you'll need a gearbox. It's all down to looking at your motor spec and comparing it with your requirements.